# Where is the best place to load initial data on Blazor WASM start up

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I am building a Blazor app and need to load some initial data when the app starts so that I can put the data into a CascadingPerameter to be used by other components.

I am wondering where the best place to call a service to read this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should use Services for data.  A service is simply an instance of a class  accessed through Dependency Injection.  Any UI component can access the same instance of that class.  The type of service depends on the scope of the data. If it's application wide and fixed during the SPA session, create a scoped or singleton service (depending on whether you're running WASM or Server) and share it though Dependency Injection.  If it's "page" scoped, use a Transient Service.

Think UI - Components, Data - Services.

The MS documentation on Services and DI is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly.)

Comment: Totally understand.  I have a service to do the loading.  What I wanted to do is to front-load a few megs of data when the app starts.  This is a long-running app and I want to keep API transactions as short as possible when moving between pages.  I have kind of settled on a service that will cache the data on the first fetch.  Not really in love with that, but I guess it will have to do until I have more time to think about it.

Comment: NP.  If you looking for ideas [Server Weather Site](https://cec-blazor-server.azurewebsites.net/) or [WAS Weather Site](https://cec-blazor-wasm.azurewebsites.net/) might help spawn some.  The code's a bit stale, I'm working on a Net5 major revision.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to inject your service into the MainLayout component, and read the data in the OnInitialized(Async) methods. But if the service can read the data in that phase of the initialization of your app, why can't you inject the service into the components that need it, instead of cascading the data ?

Comment: The reason for cascading the data is because every component will need access to it.  I did try putting it into the MainLayout but ran into some issues with undefined.  Don't remember which ones.