# Calling ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly app lifecycle event in MainLayout or App - Breakpoint never hits

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

**Update:**

Thanks to @SergioJunior. The code is indeed executed but for some reason I can't get a break point to stick until I navigate to `/`. Why is this?

I have a breakpoint in every method but it does not get hit until i navigate to `/`.

[image]

The only break point that hits:

[image]

Github link to reproduce:

https://github.com/Ogglas/BlazorTest

**Original:**

I want to run a lifecycle event during Blazor WebAssembly app initial load. I therefore tried to place a code block in `MainLayout.razor` and `App.razor` but the method is never called. If I place the exact same method in `Index.razor` it works fine when I load the page `/`. Why can't I call a lifecycle event in `MainLayout.razor` or `App.razor`?

```
@code{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Method();
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#lifecycle-events-1

According to the answer below it should be possible to do it but it does not work for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66022236/3850405

Comment: Do you mind sharing App.razor, MainLayout, and Index.razor? My app does exactly the same thing and it works fine.

Comment: @MayurEkbote Updated with complete Github example and a more correct explanation. The code is indeed executed but for some reason the breakpoint is not hit until i navigate to page ´/`.

Comment: I can see all three lines in the debug window. i.e. OnInitializedAsync App
OnInitializedAsync MainLayout
OnInitializedAsync Index

Comment: @MayurEkbote Correct - but I can't get a breakpoint to stick until I navigate to `/`

Comment: Me neither. I think it's blazor webassembly specific problem. If you are doing some complex app development (I mean anything beyond hello world), I highly recommend you develop it for blazor server and then port to webassembly.

Comment: @MayurEkbote Reported a Github issue, you should not need to use Blazor Server and then port to WebAssembly for complete debugging. :)
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36861

Comment: Of course! I have a long-running angsty thread on VS. The reason I recommended that is because the debug experience on Web assembly is poor. Specifically, you get javascript elements at the debug point. If you debug in the Blazor server, you get C# elements. That is vastly more useful I think :)

Answer (score 0):

I have made a test and all lifecycle events works fine inside `MainLayout.razor`.
Have you forgot something?

```
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initialized");
    }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("InitializedAsync");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ParametersSet");
    }

    protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ParametersSetAsync");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AfterRender");
    }

    protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AfterRenderAsync");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

[Console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ3FV.png)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Updated with a more correct explanation. It is indeed only the breakpoint that is not hit, the code is actually executed.